# Dealing with images in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn how to use Images stored in the server using a Database

---

In server my image is in the location `/images/image.jpg`

---

I have created a database called `test456`

I have a table named `MyTable` in the database `test456`

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
_id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
Image VARCHAR(50)
);
```

I read a post that involved

### Store the image location in the `filesystem`, than store it directly in the `DB`.

- What is meant by it?
- How to achieve this?

Comment: Just store the name of the image (in your case it is image.jpg) to the db and thats it. You know where it is located so just retrieve it from db and display it wherever needed

Comment: Also, varchar(50) may not be a good idea depending on how you intend to store the url. If just filename then you might be safe, but if you're doing a full path that might be limiting. Yeah, not a good idea to have huge paths, but you never know. Suppose you're storing user  uploaded files and preserving filenames. A user MIGHT upload a file with a ridiculous name. Alternatively, you could rename the uploaded images with their id's and store the path to the renamed file. That could be safe with varchar(50). Storing images in the DB COULD mean storing the bytes of a file using a blob data type

Comment: in the  database you  can just store the path of  image you need  to upload image to your perticular folder and after the  save the path of that image in database  to call the  path any time in image source to show your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload the image in the directory(server location of the image) and store the image path in the database as VARCHAR

Comment: Can you give a insert statement for the location i have mentioned in your answer, Thanks

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661411/saving-filepath-of-uploaded-image-to-mysql-database

Comment: `<td>Image</td> 
    <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image"></td>
    
    <?php     if(!empty($_FILES)){
      $filename=$_FILES['image']['name'];
      $filetype=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
      
      $query = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Image) VALUES ('".$filename."');";
      mysql_query($query);
     }
    ?>`

Answer (score 0):

table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    _id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    imagePath VARCHAR(50)
);
```

HTML/PHP

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['imagePath'] ?>" />
```