# PHP - Upload input="file" image to ftp directory and display direct link of image

Tags: php, image, file, input, ftp

I'm trying to make this sort of very simple image-hosting website.
I'm using the code below to upload the images from the `input="file"` to my ftp directory. The next step is to display the direct image link (*eg: www.example.com/123.png*) right after uploading on a different page.

```
<?php

  $ftp_server = "myftp.co.uk";
  $ftp_user_name = "myusername";
  $ftp_user_pass = "mypass";
  $destination_file = "/public_html/my/directory/";
  $source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

  // set up basic connection
  $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
  ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

  // login with username and password
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

  // check connection
  if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
  } else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
  }

  // upload the file
  $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

  // check upload status
  if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
  } else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
  }

  // close the FTP stream 
  ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

I have no idea how to do this. I checked everywhere and couldn't find a place that explains how to do this.

Comment: Why you are using FTP ? Simple move_uploaded_file should work! Any reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721984/php-upload-image-then-show/30722617#30722617  ?